# Optimize this mysql query GROUP BY + ORDER BY + UNION ALL

Tags: mysql

```
SELECT * FROM (
                SELECT qid,via,date,uid, via as cool FROM questions WHERE via != '' AND (uid = 3 OR `uid` IN (SELECT uid_followed FROM followers WHERE uid_follower =  3 AND unfollowed = 0))
                AND via NOT IN (SELECT qid FROM votes WHERE uid =  3)
                UNION ALL
                SELECT qid,via,date,uid, qid as cool FROM questions WHERE via = '' AND (uid = 3 OR `uid` IN (SELECT uid_followed FROM followers WHERE uid_follower =  3 AND unfollowed = 0))
                AND qid NOT IN (SELECT qid FROM votes WHERE uid =  3)
                ) as a
                GROUP BY cool
                ORDER BY date DESC
```

It takes over 3 seconds and I have put indexes on columns qid and via in the correct columns.
The complexity is that I want a unique qid and that some rows have qid but are infact hyperlinks to other qids via the via field.
And the qid most not have an entry in votes for uid = 3 (userID 3)
Plus it must be sorted cronologically.

Comment: What are you trying to do with that `GROUP BY`? You have no aggregates (`MAX(),MIN(),SUM(),COUNT()` etc) and only one of several columns in the `GROUP BY`. MySQL permits that where most others don't, but with potentially indeterminate results.

Comment: Could it be your database server is heavily used?

Comment: getting a unique qid/via

Comment: @Chris Yes - but I would still like to see if it can be written more optimized

Comment: You'll need to post your table structure, the relevant `SHOW CREATE TABLE` statements.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT qid,via,date,uid,
case
    when via = '' then qid
    else via
end as cool
FROM questions
WHERE (via != ''
AND via NOT IN (SELECT qid FROM votes WHERE uid =  3)
OR via = ''
AND qid NOT IN (SELECT qid FROM votes WHERE uid =  3))
AND (uid = 3 OR `uid` IN (SELECT uid_followed FROM followers WHERE uid_follower =  3 AND unfollowed = 0))
ORDER BY date DESC
```

Without UNION ALL and GROUP BY

Tell me if it's ok. I compact two queries in one using OR logic operator.

You don't take care about NULL value of via field. I use your notation (!= '' or = '') but perhaps you'd consider NULL value.

Comment: Thanks so much! I did not know about the case thing!